# Using HTML Placeholder in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, placeholder

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}
```

This is my code, I want to add Username as placeholder in the text box. I already use bootstrap in the project.

I tried to use the example

```
{{ Form::text('username', 'Username', Input::old('username')) }}
```

But it gives a default value which needs to be deleted and then the user has to type his value. I want something like how it shows up on Twitter.com etc. Which gets erased once user types into it.

Comment: +1 for the Input::old(), never knew about that until now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'),  array('placeholder'=>'Username')) }}
```

This works for Laravel 4!!

Comment: for password fields you might want to use `{{ Form::password('field-name',array('placeholder' => 'placeholder text', 'class' => 'class-name')}}` hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

```
{{ Form::text('username', null, array('placeholder'=>'Username' )); }}
```

Comment: This is actually a workable answer as it removes and replaces unnecessary arguments with short and concise code.This should be the correct answer as the question only requested for a way to add placeholdes to form elements with laravel 4. I repeat , this is the right answer

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
{{ Form::text('txtUsername', '',array('class'=>'input', 'placeholder'=>'Username')) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since this was updated but with Former for Laravel the way to do this would be:

```
Former::text('field')->placeholder('langfile.path.to.placeholder.text')))
```

The lang file would be called langfile.php with the array containing:

```
<?php

    return array (  
        'path.to.placeholder.text' => 'Some Placeholder Text.'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody wonders how this should work for a password field:

```
{{ Form::password('password',  array('placeholder'=>'Password')) }}
```